# Web service (asmx) to read in customer's soap message c# - null object error

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am pretty new with web services and WSDLs.

What I want to do is to build a web service to read in a customer's SOAP message and process it.

The soap message sent to me is as follows (note I have trimmed the SOAP message right down)

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap2:Header>
  <wsa:Action>http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest</wsa:Action> 
  <wsa:ReplyTo>
   <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address> 
  </wsa:ReplyTo>
 </soap2:Header>
 <Body>
  <OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>
   <POS>
     //More tags
   </POS>
   <HotelReservations>
    <HotelReservation RoomStayReservation="true">
     <UniqueID Type="14" ID="59071IC000041" /> 
    </HotelReservation>
   </HotelReservations>
  </OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This is my web service asmx (again I have trimmed it right down)

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]

public OTA_HotelResNotifRS ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest(OTA_HotelResNotifRQ OTA_HotelResNotifRQ)
{

}
```

Problem: When the message comes in, the method ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest gets fired but OTA_HotelResNotifRQ is null. The customer gave me the WSDL, as far as am concerned the class is correct. Though I notice the `<Body>` tag and is not `<soap2:Body>`. Does this make a difference?

I cannot change customer's message, I can only change my web service to read what they have sent to me. Am I missing something in my asmx?

If you are interested, here is their WSDL  https://interface.synxis.com/interface/ota2010av2/OTA2010A.svc.wsdl

Comment: You should use WCF services instead, asmx web services are a legacy technology.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The only knowledge I have is building in asmx web services and not WCF. So it's best to stick with what I know so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

I changed the namespace for a couple of the classes, which affected the schema files in the WSDL.

Comment: oh!. I m also getting struggle with that. Can u pls post the class in net